# edit frame height Collection reusable View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, uicollectionreusableview

*using Xcode 7.0 beta, Swift 2.0, IOS 9 supported*

I have a View Controller, which contains a Collection View. Inside is a **header:** Collection Reusable View, a **collection:** Collection View Cell and a **footer:** Collection Reusable View.

Inside the header, I have the functionality to login, register or logout.
Depending on what button is clicked, Views inside this header will be hidden or not. Now the last thing I have to do is re-size the frame height of the header view (Collection Reusable View). Because when logged in, both RegisterView and LoginView will be hidden which will leave a large amount of empty space.

here is an image of my structure:

[image: structure views]

I quickly noticed that I'm unable to add any constraints to the Collection Reusable View :(

All the functionality for the header Collection Reusable View is inside a class that extends `UICollectionReusableView`. I'm able to read `self.frame.height`, but I cannot write to it. I seem to be able to edit the frame (why is height read-only, while frame is not, apple?). This however has no effect, even `self.frame = CGRectZero` doesn't do anything.

I noticed I can do this inside the main ViewController.swift, when initializing the header and footer (`func collectionView, switch on kind -> UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`), but this is not what I want as it should change on button click.

For now, I move the RegisterView up (I edit the top constraint in the code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly manipulate the size of a view in a collection view.  To control their sizes, your collection view's delegate should conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, then you can return whatever size you like for the header in that section by implementing the method `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` on that protocol.  If the header should not be visible, simply return `0.0`for its height.  Once you've changed the state of your view controller in a way that will require an update to this layout, call `invalidateLayout()` on the collection view's layout to trigger these layout methods on your delegate to be called.

```
class MyCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var shouldHideHeader: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    let defaultHeaderSize: CGFloat = 100.0
    let loginHeaderSectionIndex: Int = 0

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if self.shouldHideHeader && section == self.loginHeaderSectionIndex {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 0.0 )
        }
        else {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: self.defaultHeaderSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I have all my functionality in the header class, what is the best way to access the shouldHideHeader var or any other methods?

Answer (score -1):

Patrick gave the correct answer for changing the header height, I however, like I said in my question, had my header functionality in a different class, so I didn't really know how to access the real viewController class.

If you keep it simple, you can just create a action link from the storyboard to that class, I had some more operations to do, and not only on respond of a button click. This is what I did:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{  

    var headerHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    var shouldChangeHeader : Bool? = false
    let loginHeaderSectionIndex: Int = 0

   func setHeaderHeight(height : CGFloat!)
   {
       headerHeight = height
       shouldChangeHeader = true
       self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
   }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind
        {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "loginHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoginHeaderView
           //you should already have this method, LoginHeaderView is the class with all the functionality for the header, we register a callback.
            headerView.registerHeightChangeCallback(setHeaderHeight)
            return headerView
       }
}
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        //here we actually change the height, best is to include a if-condition, so it won't change on loading unless you especially call it.
        if self.shouldChangeHeader && self.loginHeaderSectionIndex == section {
            shouldChangeHeader = false
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: headerHeight )
        }
        else {
            //do nothing, keep as it is now.
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height) /
        }
    }
}

class LoginHeaderView : UICollectionReusableView {

    var heightCallback : ((height : CGFloat!)-> Void)?
    func registerHeightChangeCallback(callback :((height : CGFloat!)-> Void)?)
    {
        heightCallback = callback
    }
    @IBAction func buttonClicked( sender: AnyObject? ) { //or from any other method...

        if(heightCallback != nil)
        {
            heightCallback!(height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```